# array_search() PHP fucntion not working on array

Tags: php, json

I am unable to have the array_search() working.

I have a string from an API call in a variable **$myresp**

`[{"name":"product 1","order_id":1,"product_type":"new","qty_ordered":1,"sku":"8057","scaffale":"B-21-B"},{"name":"Product 2","order_id":1,"product_type":"old","qty_ordered":1,"sku":"8057","scaffale":"B-21-B"}]`

I then use **$mydata = json_decode($myresp);** to get an array format

Using **print_r($mydata);** returns me

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Product 1 [order_id] => 1 [product_type] => new [qty_ordered] => 1 [sku] => 8057 [scaffale] => B-21-B ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Product 2 [order_id] => 1 [product_type] => old [qty_ordered] => 1 [sku] => 8057 [scaffale] => B-21-B ) )`

If I try using **echo array_search("new", $mydata);** I am expecting to get the value of the key of the array tha contains value = **new** (in this case array 0) .

Unfortunately is doing nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use json_encode with the second parameter set true, so that it returns an associative array otherwise it will return an array of objects. In your case it will return a multidimensional array.

```
$mydata = json_decode($myresp, true); //mydata is a multidimensional array
```

To find the value in $mydata, you can use

```
$key = array_search('new', array_column($mydata, 'product_type'));
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly !!